# Checking equal values and data types

Tags: php

Will the following check both value and data type equality:

```
if ($fooBar != $fooBarNew)
```

Comment: The [friendly manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) tells you all you need to know if you read it.... there's even some useful tables [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) showing exactly how it works

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`===`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) comparison operator like so:

```
if ($fooBar === $fooBarNew) {
    // both variables are identical on value and type level
}
```